# How to disabled tap and hold popover for touchable devices

Tags: html, ipad

How to disabled tap and hold popover for touchable devices

Screenshot is here
http://screencast.com/t/D4sqtrwEMQPD

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution.

```
/* css code to hide popover in touchable devoices*/
.hide-popover>*
{
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
}
```

- Here  .hide-popover is selector
  You need to check it in a touchable device